# Is there any difference in the dist/ folder generated when ember build vs ember serve?

Tags: ember.js, serve

When I run ember serve, a new dist folder is generated every time. Is this folder the same as the one generated when I run  ember build?

Answer (score 3):

No difference. It's same unless you specify environment flag.
Both `ember build` and `ember server` if you didn't specify `--environment` flag (possible values are development,production) by default it will build for development environment.

In [ember-cli user guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli) explained clearly,

**ember build**

> Builds the application into the dist/ directory (customize via the --output-path flag). Use the --environment flag to specify the build environment (defaults to development). Use the --watch flag to keep the process running and rebuilding when changes occur.

**ember server**

> Starts the server. The default port is 4200. Use the --proxy flag to proxy all ajax requests to the given address. For example, ember server --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080 will proxy all ajax requests to the server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080. Aliases: ember s, ember serve

Answer (score 3):

It is almost the same but with one crucial difference.

When you run `ember serve` it will also hook you up with livereload by injecting `<script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` into the head tag.

This makes the content of the `dist`-folder unsuitable for anything other then running it via Ember CLI.